# Why is my fragment caching writing so much?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached

I'm using fragment caching in Rails 3 and I see a write for nearly every single read.  I only have a delete cache when an individual record is change:

```
after_save do
    Rails.cache.delete("#{self.class.table_name}_for_environment_#{merchant_id}")
    Rails.cache.delete("jobs_index_table_environment_#{merchant_id}_job_#{self}")
    Rails.cache.delete("tech_archives_page_environment_#{merchant_id}_job_#{self}")
  end

  after_destroy do
    Rails.cache.delete("#{self.class.table_name}_for_environment_#{merchant_id}")
    Rails.cache.delete("jobs_index_table_environment_#{merchant_id}_job_#{self}")
    Rails.cache.delete("tech_archives_page_environment_#{merchant_id}_job_#{self}")
  end
```

What I observe with the cache is that nearly every record is both read and written on every request.  This is not my understanding of how caching works, so obviously I'm messing something up.

Here is a snippet of comments:

```
2015-10-19T16:06:39.939351+00:00 app[web.2]: Read fragment views/job_comments_comment_#<Comment:0x007f9aa9b69860> 1.7ms
2015-10-19T16:06:39.955819+00:00 app[web.2]: Read fragment views/job_comments_comment_#<Comment:0x007f9aa9b69450> 10.1ms
2015-10-19T16:06:39.945527+00:00 app[web.2]: Write fragment views/job_comments_comment_#<Comment:0x007f9aa9b69860> 1.9ms
2015-10-19T16:06:39.999099+00:00 app[web.2]: Write fragment views/job_comments_comment_#<Comment:0x007f9aa9b69450> 42.6ms
```

So far as I can tell, the two objects there being read and written are the same (memory is identical between the sets for read and write).

As the comment (in this case), hasn't changed, why is being written to the cache?  Shouldn't it only be read?

EDIT:

I *think* that I understand it better now - I chanced upon a blog that had this wonderful snippet:

> You can give an Array to cache and your cache key will be based on a
>   concatenated version of everything in the Array. This is useful for
>   different caches that use the same ActiveRecord objects.

And holy cow does that clear things up in my head.

I re-use the same AR objects on multiple views for various reasons, and I discovered the hard way you cannot simply:

```
<% cache(ar) do %>
```

On every page because it will bring the HTML and styling with it.  So I renamed each of my cache keys something like:

```
<% cache("this_specific_page_#{ar}") do %>
```

But with the variable interpolation, it seems that each of these cache keys is unique.

Passing it as an array of args to the cache method makes it function as expected (I think - still testing).

So now I have:

```
<% cache(["this_specific_page", session[:key], ar]) do %>
```

This separates the objects per page as I need, but it maintains that a single ar record is just that - free of the string I had it concatenated with earlier.

Comment: the cache key generation should use to_param on the comment (usually just `id`), but it looks like it's writing the comment object.id (all this stuff `#<Comment:0x007f9aa9b69860>`.  What's in ar?